# How can I process ExtJS 4.2.1 tree item text before it is rendered?

Tags: extjs

I need to swap the localization IDs with their actual string values (for the current locale) in tree data.

So if there were an event such as renderTreeItem, in its handler I might do this, where StringMessage.getResource(id) returns the localized string for the id:

```
onRenderTreeItem(text) {
return StringMessage.getResource(text)
}

root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I use a convert function in the tree model.